# JavaScript :How do I mark an item with style color without using any other unique identifiers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a to do list: [image: (sample output)]

What I intend to do is for each task if I click on the tick symbol it should convert to yellow meaning complete. Now the problem is that for the first element it works pretty well i.e it toggles between white and yellow (meaning task is completed) but if I add more than one task then it does not work(no action at all). I am not thinking of adding dynamic id or classes with numbers. How do I fix them.

Now I am returning this lower portion in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)and the returned html looks like this:

```
<div class="row datasection">
  <div class="todo">
    <div class="databox col s6 offset-s1 waves-effect">
      <p class="checkglyph1 checkglyph2">Task no 1</p>
      <a>
        <i class="material-icons checkglyph checkglyph1 checkglyph2 glyphcolor">check</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var calendardata = document.getElementById('date1');
var addbutton = document.querySelector('.addbutton');
var todo = document.querySelector('.todo');
addbutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /* body to return the html */
  if (data.value) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <button> element
    newdiv.classList.add("databox", "col", "s6", "waves-effect");
    //console.log(newdiv);
    todo.appendChild(newdiv);
    //console.log(newdiv.parentNode);
    var newpar = document.createElement("p");
    newpar.classList.add("checkglyph1", "checkglyph2");
    var node = document.createTextNode(data.value + "." + "      " + calendardata.value);
    var newa = document.createElement("a");
    newdiv.appendChild(newa)
    var newglyph = document.createElement("i");
    newglyph.classList.add("material-icons", "checkglyph", "checkglyph1", "checkglyph2", "glyphcolor");
    var node1 = document.createTextNode("check");
    newa.appendChild(newglyph);
    newglyph.append(node1);
    newpar.appendChild(node);
    newdiv.appendChild(newpar);
    data.value = "";
    calendardata.value = "";
    created = true;
    console.log("before glyh created");

    //code to perform action on the click of the tick symbol

    var glyph = document.querySelector(".glyphcolor");
    var par = document.getElementsByClassName('checkglyph2');
    console.log(glyph);
    console.log(par.length);

    console.log(this);
    glyph.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log("This is :")
      console.log(this);
      glyph.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
      console.log(this)
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: @trincot can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the code responsible for marking a task as complete should be outside the click event (i.e `addbutton`), also you have to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all `.glyphcolor` elements, iterate over and add event listener to each one of them:

```
var glyph= document.querySelectorAll(".glyphcolor");

for (var i = 0; i < glyph.length; i++) {
    glyph[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        this.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
    });
}
```

Remember that [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) always return the first matched element that's why it works only for the first task

**EDIT:** create glyph listener during the task creation: each task added, attach a listener to `i` element:

```
...
var newglyph = document.createElement("i");
newglyph.classList.add("material-icons", "checkglyph", "checkglyph1", "checkglyph2", "glyphcolor");
newglyph.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    this.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
});
var node1 = document.createTextNode("check");
...
```

Comment: i placed it inside because initially var glyph= document.querySelectorAll(".glyphcolor"); is empty because it has not been created.Now only after it is created we can add it.Another alternative would be to return a variable indicating that glyphcolor class exists.

Comment: I did it the same way but let us say I created two tasks now when I click on the first task it does not respond.Technically when I click on that eventlistener then this should point to that,but here nothing is happening.

Comment: I just tested that on chrome console, and worked for me

Comment: are we not doing the same when we add an eventlistener to glyph.

Comment: no add listener to `newglyph`, look at my edited answer

Comment: yes I saw that, but is it not similar to adding eventlistener to glyph variable using the loop?

Comment: no, now you'll add listener to each created element there is no need to select them all and then looping through each one and add listener

Comment: ok I tried the looping part but it does not work if there are more than one tasks.i.e the eventlisitener does not work on the first one i.eif I click on the first task it does not toggle but works fairly well for the last entered one.I donot understand that art.PS:I am a beginner

Comment: I just want to know where I went wrong so that I can grow. @YouneL

Comment: @leo have tried putting debugger in event listerens?

Comment: I did but cannot see anything new happening.Cannot understand where it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

wrap toggle button with item to change color into same parent.

when clicking on the button, in event handler `this` will point to that button. You can query it's parent and then navigate to item and toggle class for making it yellow, or change the inline styled of this element manually.

Comment: can you please elaborate.I mean why it is not working in my current implementation as I have set event listener to the check button already(I .assumed all child elements will have glyphcolor so event listener is set.)